How to Bypass CORS When Streaming YouTube M3U8 and TS Files Using HLS.js?
I'm creating a Flask app that fetches a YouTube video manifest (.m3u8 file) and streams it using an HLS player in the browser. The flow is as follows:
My Flask app gets the .m3u8 link from YouTube using yt-dlp.
I pass the .m3u8 URL to the HLS HTML player in the browser.
The player attempts to fetch the .m3u8 manifest and the .ts segments, but I encounter CORS errors.
Here is the error message I get in the browser console:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_variant/expire/..../file/index.m3u8' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I tried downloading the .m3u8 file manually and pointing the player to it. This works for the manifest but fails for the .ts video files due to the same CORS issue.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://rr2---sn-8vq54voxxb-j5pk.googlevideo.com/.../sug.ts' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Also i tried to play m3u8 link using VLC App and Safari It's Played the video normally without any problem
Can some one help me to solve CORS Problem and play m3u8 using hls?
